# XML layout issue

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to expand my XML layout as I have a number of buttons I need to put on one screen. I have added a scrollview under my textview and image view but cant seem to get the layout to expand? I'm also getting an XML error layout on my scrollview of:

```
error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
```

Here's my layout showing the expansion issue. Can anyone gibe me an Idea of what I'm doing wrong?:

[image: pic]

Heres my XML - Im aware i have duplicate information. This is a test.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLink"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:src="@drawable/menulist" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.14"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/addconmenu"
        android:src="@drawable/addconmenu"
        android:text="Contacts List" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/todo"
        android:text="&apos;To Do&apos; List" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/musicmenu"
        android:src="@drawable/musicmenu"
        android:text="Music List" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="20dp"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/shoppingmenu"
           android:src="@drawable/shoppingmenu"
           android:text="Shopping List" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_margin="20dp"
               android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gymmenu"
               android:src="@drawable/gymmenu"
               android:text="Gym List" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_margin="20dp"
               android:drawableLeft="@drawable/appointmentmenu"
               android:src="@drawable/appointmentmenu"
               android:text="Appointment List" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you should reverse the order of the last two lines of your layout. You are closing the `ScrollView` tag after closing the top-level `LinearLayout` tag.

Comment: Thanks Ted, that fixed the issue with the error! Cant believe i missed it. I still cant expand the view though so I can see the other 2 buttons. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @user1352057 - I would set the top-level `LinearLayout` to have `android:layout_height="match_parent"` instead of `wrap_content`. Does the scroll view not scroll?

Answer (score 1):

The Linear Layout height inside of your ScrollView is wrapcontent if you make it match parent or fillparent it will solve your problem.